# How do I automatically change my package.json version while using gitflow, Jenkins and Node?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, git-flow

Is their a plugin or should I use Grunt? I can't seems to find anything online... any help would be very much appreciated

thanks

Comment: I only know about [git version](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but i only used it in MVC5 projetcs

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options you can benefit from:

**Option 1:**
Check out [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) docs.

**Option 2:**
If you are using Grunt, you can probably use [grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump).

Usage:

```
grunt bump
>> Version bumped to 0.0.2

grunt bump:patch
>> Version bumped to 0.0.3

grunt bump:minor
>> Version bumped to 0.1.0

grunt bump:major
>> Version bumped to 1.0.0
```

***PS:*** *If you are using Gulp, there is a [gulp-bump](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump) package.*